# Docker-compose error: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on microservice using docker on visual studio 2017. I’ve been dealing with this error for half a day.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Creating network "dockercompose8357222465790585823_default" with the default driver
Building Pricing.api
invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

Here is the compose content 
version: '3'

```
services:
  Pricing.api:
    image: Pricing.api
    build:
      context: ../PricingAPI
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PricingAPI.dll"]
```

Here is the ci 
version: '3'

```
services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-2.0
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./Pricing.MicroService.sln && dotnet publish ./Pricing.MicroService.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

what is it referring  when it says by repository ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that by repository it meant ‘service’. I updated service name as show bellow and it works.

```
 services:
      Pricing.api: => pricing.api with lowercase ‘p’
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        ports:
          - "80"
```

It should have said

> invalid reference format. Service name must be lowercase .

This is a confusing error message. This is something Docker team has to fix imo.

Comment: All of my services are lower case and I still get this error. I am hosting .Net Core in Windows Container. I can connect via SSMS, but I get this same silly error when I try to connect from my api